# How is the standard deviation of VAE's constructed?

Tags: probability, neural-networks, normal-distribution, autoencoders

I am trying to build a Variational Autoencoder. I was looking at various codes online and found most of them in some way or another copy Francois Chollet (Google researchers) [code](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html).

Now my main question with this code is this part:

> First, here's our encoder network, mapping inputs to our latent
>   distribution parameters:
>
> ```
> x = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, original_dim))
> h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(x)
> z_mean = Dense(latent_dim)(h)
> z_log_sigma = Dense(latent_dim)(h)
> ```
>
> We can use these parameters to sample new similar points from the
>   latent space:
>
> ```
> def sampling(args):
>     z_mean, z_log_sigma = args
>     epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, latent_dim),
>                               mean=0., std=epsilon_std)
>     return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_sigma) * epsilon
>
> # note that "output_shape" isn't necessary with the TensorFlow backend
> # so you could write `Lambda(sampling)([z_mean, z_log_sigma])`
> z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,))([z_mean, z_log_sigma])
> ```

As you can clearly see the $log(\sigma) = \mu$. Where did this assumption come from? How is it possible that we generate a random normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean and log-variance are both encoded *in the same way*, but they have their own connections leading up to them from the encoding part $h$. Further on in the example, you will see that both `z_mean` and `z_log_sigma` are concatenated into a single layer.

I'm not too familiar with python, but in [the same example given for the R interface to Keras](https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/examples/variational_autoencoder.html), you can see this quite literally, as the function is called `layer_concatenate`.

> ```
> z <- layer_concatenate(list(z_mean, z_log_var)) %>%
>   layer_lambda(sampling)
> ```

(`layer_lambda` takes this concatenated input and evaluates the function `sampling`.)

Perhaps this explicit concatenation is not necessary in the python version due to differences in how R and python work.

Comment: Yeah..I read it somewhere and yes i actually was not familiar with keras.. But can you tell something why is it not variance but log(variance)?

Comment: Good question! I searched the paper and couldn't find and explanation by the authors, but I assume it is because $\exp(x) > 0 \,\forall x$, and $\exp(\log(x)) = x$, so it is a way to ensure the variance is always positive. It might also just be for numerical stability, or convenience elsewhere in their derivations.